# how to remove horizontal black lines in outlook mailer

Tags: html, user-interface, html-email

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);" width="650">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;" valign="top">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main" width="586">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                    <!-- 2-column 1 Start-->
                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="two-column" style=
                                    "border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="275">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" style="margin-bottom:16px; font-family:'Times New Roman',Serif;" valign="top">
                                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="240">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="font-size:13px; line-height:20px; font-family: 'Crimson Text'; color:#d6a6a2;" valign=
                                                                "top"><span class="address">Jess Neil<br>
                                                                5000 S Broad Street<br>
                                                                Building 18<br>
                                                                Philadelphia, PA 19148<br>
                                                                XXX(Courntry Code)<br>
                                                                215.454.3686</span></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table><!-- 2-column 1 End--><!-- 2-column 2 Start  -->
                                    <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="two-column m-left0 m-top15" style=
                                    "border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" width="275">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" style=" margin-bottom:16px; font-family:'Times New Roman',Serif;" valign="top">
                                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="240">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding:0px 0px 20px 0px; font-size:18px; font-family: 'Crimson Text'; color:#000000;"
                                                                valign="top">
                                                                    Shipment Number:<a href="#" style="color:#c96388;">XXXXX</a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding:14px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:18px; font-family: 'Crimson Text'; color:#000000;"
                                                                valign="top">Standard Shipping</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding:1px 0px; font-size:13px; font-family: 'Crimson Text'; color:#d6a6a2;" valign="top">
                                                                Email Shipmethod Deliver days total ship free</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table><!-- 2-column 2 End-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[you can see the horizontal black line in the below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSY4x.png)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);"`